# Returning a ptr to a stack buffer

Tags: c++

I've come across the function below:

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


std::string getErrnoString(const int errorNumber)
{
    const int maxLength = 256;
    char buffer[maxLength];
    return strerror_r(errorNumber, buffer, maxLength);
}
```

My specific question is regarding what the function returns.
It looks like it returns a pointer to 'buffer' . Which is on the stack - right?

Isn't that a problem?

Comment: There seem to be at least 2 versions of the function, returning int or char*: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the function `strerror_r` uses `buffer` to store the message and returns it, but since the function `getErrnoString` returns a `std::string` then an [implicit conversion constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) is called:

```
string::string(const char* data)
```

This constructor copies the data from the passed pointer to the internal buffer of the `std::string` itself so there are no problems since you then return a copy of the buffer stored in a `std::string` which you return by value.

Answer (score 2):

The above code does not return a pointer to the local buffer. It does not return any pointers at all. It returns an `std::string` object constructed from the char buffer returned by `strerror_r`. It is perfectly safe to return `std::string` objects by value.

The `return` statement in this function performs an implicit conversion to `std::string` type. In explicit form it would look as follows

```
return std::string(strerror_r(errorNumber, buffer, maxLength));
```

P.S. Note though that GNU-specific version of `strerror_r` used in the above code does not guarantee that the function will use the user-supplied buffer. The function is allowed to return a pointer to a system buffer, leaving the user-supplied buffer unused. But in general case the user has to assume that the user-supplied buffer will be used for the string.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a `std::string` returned from function `strerror_r(errorNumber, buffer, maxLength);`

You are passing pointer to 'buffer' as a parameter to function `strerror_r` with other parameters like `maxlength` and `errorNumber`.